# How do I select from IF(....) as 'A'

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I Don't know what to say it.
It was like

```
SELECT

(IF(ISNULL(fieldA),'it is null','fieldA')) AS 'I_want_this',

'I_want_this' as 'Show'

from table
```

Comment: Look up `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

```
select 
   case when fieldA is NULL then 'It is null' else fieldA as I_Want_This
from Table
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()`. It will print the value of first parameter if it's not null other will print second parameter.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table tableA(fieldA varchar(10));
 insert into tableA values(null);
 insert into tableA values('a');
 insert into tableA values('b');
 insert into tableA values(null);
 insert into tableA values('c');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(fieldA,'it is null') AS 'I_want_this'
 from tableA
```

Output:

| I_want_this |
| --- |
| it is null |
| a |
| b |
| it is null |
| c |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7dc51fc40eb73efd324e0745afa97682)*